# Generate initial guess for any function?

Tags: algorithm, math, newtons-method

Here is the [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) code from Wikipedia page:

```
x0            = 1         # The initial guess
f(x)          = x^2 - 2   # The function whose root we are trying to find
fprime(x)     = 2x        # The derivative of the function
tolerance     = 1e-7      # 7 digit accuracy is desired
epsilon       = 1e-14     # Do not divide by a number smaller than this
maxIterations = 20        # Do not allow the iterations to continue indefinitely
solutionFound = false     # Have not converged to a solution yet

for i = 1:maxIterations
  y      = f(x0)
  yprime = fprime(x0)

  if abs(yprime) < epsilon            # Stop if the denominator is too small
    break
  end

  global x1 = x0 - y/yprime           # Do Newton's computation

  if abs(x1 - x0) <= tolerance        # Stop when the result is within the desired tolerance
    global solutionFound = true
    break
  end

  global x0 = x1                      # Update x0 to start the process again
end

if solutionFound
  println("Solution: ", x1)           # x1 is a solution within tolerance and maximum number of iterations
else
  println("Did not converge")         # Newton's method did not converge
end
```

When I implement this I see that there are cases I need to apply new initial guess:

- When functions (i.e: `f, fPrime`) give Infinity or NaN result (e.g in C#, this happens when `result = 1/x when x=0`, `result = √x when x=-1`,...)
- When `abs(yprime) < epsilon`
- When `x0` is too large for `y/yprime` (e.g `x0` = 1e99 but `y/yprime` = 1e25, this will make `x1 = x0` while it's mathematically wrong, this will make the algorithm leads to nowhere).

My app allows user to input the math function and the initial guess, (e.g: Initial guess for `x` can be `1e308`, function can be `9=√(-81+x)`, `45=InverseSin(x)`, `3=√(x-1e99)`,... ).

So when the initial guess is bad, my app will automatically apply the new initial guess with hope that it can give the result.

My current solution: <strike>the initial guess is the array of values</strike>:

```
double[] arrInitialGuess = 
{
[User's initial guess], 0, 1, -1, 2, -2,... (you know, Factorial n!)..., 7.257416E+306, -7.257416E+306,
}
```

I have the following questions:

1. Is the big number (e.g 7.257416E+306) even needed? because I see that in `x1 = x0 - y/yprime`, if the initial guess `x0` is too big compare to `y/yprime`, it programmatically leads to nowhere. If the big number is pointless, what is the cap for initial guess (e.g 1e17?)

<strike>2. What is better for the array of initial guess: the factorial n! `{+-1, +-2, +-6,...}`, or 2^x `{+-2^0, +-2^1, +-2^2,...}`, or 10^x `{+-1e0, +-1e1, +-1e2,...}`,...</strike>

3. If my predefined-array-initial-guess method is not good, is there any better way to get new initial guess for Newton's method? (e.g an algorithm to get next initial-guess?)

### **Update:**

Change of thought, the pre-defined array of initial guess doesn't work.
For example, I have the formula: `8=3/x => y=8-3/x` which gives this graph
[image: Graph y=8-3/x]
In this case, I can find the solution when initial guess is in the range `[ 0.1 ; 0.7 ]`, so if I have the pre-defined initial guess arrray = `{0, 1, 2,..., Inf}`, it won't do me any good but wasting my precious resource.

So my new thought now is: steering the next initial guess base on the graph. The idea is: applying the last guess and compare with current guess to see that the value of y is heading toward 0 or not, so that I can determine to increase or decrease the next initial guess to steer the y toward 0. But I still consider the pre-defined initial guess idea in case the guesses all give Infinity value.

### Update 2:

New thought: pick the new initial guess in the range `[ x0; x1 ]` where

1. there is no error between x0 and x1 (e.g there is no error divide by zero when apply a value in the range `[ x0; x1 ]`). So I can form the line AB: A(x0, y0) and B(x1, y1).
2. y0 and y1 have different sign: `(y0 > 0 && y1 < 0) || (y0 < 0 && y1 > 0)`. So that the line AB can cut the x axis (which cause a big possibility there is an y = 0 somewhere between y0 and y1, if the graph isn't too weird).

Try to narrow the range [ x0; x1 ] as small as possible, then run a few initial guesses between the range.

Comment: *"I have the following questions:"*: you should ask only one question, as otherwise it will be closed as too broad.

Comment: I wonder if you can come up with an initial guess. I do believe this is completely up to the function at hand. I do not see the benefit either for you or the user. To be able to use Newtons method, you need to understand the function and what you try to solve. Your initial number (x0) is not an initial guess but a math calculation.

Comment: Newton's method is notorious for sensitivity to the initial iteration point. It's just a characteristic of the algorithm. Other numerical zero-finders are more robust, but often slower. Bisection - one of the slowest - is guaranteed to converge. There are no free lunches.